# Swagger UI behind google end point

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, google-kubernetes-engine, loopback

I've setup a Google Endpoint in front of a Google Container Engine service. The container is running Loopback, which serves the swagger UI by default at `/explorer`. I would like to access the UI, but of course the Google end point prevents accessing as it isn't part of the API spec.

Google has [these docs](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/adding-swagger), but they seem to be specific to an app engine deployment.

How can I go about exposing the swagger UI while using Google Endpoints, Google Container Engine and swagger?

Comment: did you figure this out?